Footer losing column display with small viewport CSS
I currently have a footer inserted to the bottom of my page. everything appears as it should on a larger viewport (above 575px). I created a media query to reduce front size below that breakpoint but it stacks the two footer sections on top of each other instead of remaining side by side in columns.
HTML
 <footer>
        <div class="container-fluid row justify-content-center mt-2">
            <span class="footer-top-left col-sm-6">
                <ul>
                    <li>Duluth Location:</li>
                    <li>6920 Grand Ave, Duluth, MN 55807</li>
                    <li>(218) 606-1150</li>
                    <li>info@perfecttimingautorepair.com</li>
                </ul>
            </span>
            <span class="footer-top-right col-sm-6">
                <ul>
                    <li> Superior Location:</li>
                    <li>4003 E 2ND ST, SUPERIOR, WI 54880</li>
                    <li>(715) 919-1384</li>
                    <li> info@perfecttimingautorepair.com</li>
                </ul>
            </span> 
                <p class="footer-bottom ms-3">
                    © Copyright 2024 Perfect Timing Auto Repair. All Rights Reserved.
                </p>
        </div>
    </footer>

CSS
/* FOOTER CSS */
body > footer > div {
    flex: 1;
}
footer { 
 position: relative;
  bottom: 0px;
  width: 100%;
  text-align: center;
  background-color: #20252b;
  color: gray;
}

body > footer > div > span.footer-top-left.col-sm-6, body > footer > div > span.footer-top-right.col-sm-6 {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
}

 /* MEDIA QUERIES */
@media (max-width: 575px) {
 .login-card {
        width: 100%;
        }
        body > div.login-card.container-lg.mt-5 > form > div > div > input:nth-child(1) ,input.form-control {
    width: 100%;
  }
  .footer-bottom, .footer-top-right, .footer-top-left {
      font-size: 0.4rem;

  }
  }
  
@media (min-width: 801px) {
    
    footer {
        position: absolute;
        bottom: 0px;
    }
}

I tried using flex-direction: column; on the body and giving the footer container a flex growth as 1 (a solution found on the web) but it hasn't worked for me.

The class col-sm-6 just does it is made for, if you always want 2 columns, no matter the screen size, then use the col-6  class. It is explained here : https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/layout/grid/

Thanks! I've realized i was using the col attribute incorrectly.

You could try the following class changes in the html to get the desired behaviour.


/* FOOTER CSS */
    body>footer>div {
      flex: 1;
    }

    footer {
      position: relative;
      bottom: 0px;
      width: 100%;
      text-align: center;
      background-color: #20252b;
      color: gray;
    }

    body>footer>div>span.footer-top-left.col-sm-6,
    body>footer>div>span.footer-top-right.col-sm-6 {
      display: flex;
      justify-content: center;
    }

    /* MEDIA QUERIES */
    @media (max-width: 575px) {
      .login-card {
        width: 100%;
      }

      body>div.login-card.container-lg.mt-5>form>div>div>input:nth-child(1),
      input.form-control {
        width: 100%;
      }

      .footer-bottom,
      .footer-top-right,
      .footer-top-left {
        font-size: 0.4rem;

      }
    }

    @media (min-width: 801px) {

      footer {
        position: absolute;
        bottom: 0px;
      }
    }
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <title>Document</title>
  <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.2/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"
    integrity="sha384-EVSTQN3/azprG1Anm3QDgpJLIm9Nao0Yz1ztcQTwFspd3yD65VohhpuuCOmLASjC" crossorigin="anonymous">
</head>

<body>
    <footer class="container-fluid p-2">
    <div class="row">
      <span class="footer-top-left col">
        <ul>
          <li>Duluth Location:</li>
          <li>6920 Grand Ave, Duluth, MN 55807</li>
          <li>(218) 606-1150</li>
          <li>info@perfecttimingautorepair.com</li>
        </ul>
      </span>
      <span class="footer-top-right col">
        <ul>
          <li> Superior Location:</li>
          <li>4003 E 2ND ST, SUPERIOR, WI 54880</li>
          <li>(715) 919-1384</li>
          <li> info@perfecttimingautorepair.com</li>
        </ul>
      </span>

    </div>
    <p class="footer-bottom ms-3">
      © Copyright 2024 Perfect Timing Auto Repair. All Rights Reserved.
    </p>
  </footer>
</body>

</html>



